# Display Pandas Dataframe in Tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I am creating a basic application to learn python.

This application will consist of a pandas dataframe displayed in a tkinter GUI where the user can select rows in the dataframe and then edit or delete the row using other separate text boxes that are populated each time a user selects a specific row.

Currently, I am only able to display my dataframe in a text box, but this needs to be a list box so users can easily select rows and scroll through the dataframe of 100 rows.

The snippets from my code are below:

```
   outp = Text(self.window,height = 10, width = 100) #declaring the text box
   outp.insert(END, df) #adding the dataframe (df) to the text box
```

I scoured the internet for an answer but the solutions are all specific to those use cases and they usually say "use a label box".

When I change Text to Listbox, then the dataframe displays in one long row.

I appreciate any input.

Comment: Why didn't try about `Treeview`?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA because I didn't know about it. I think that will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using Treeview.

Snippet of the code is below:

```
def df_to_list(self,df):

    self.tree["columns"] = df.columns.values.tolist()
    for x in range(len(df.columns.values)):
        self.tree.column(df.columns.values[x], width=100)
        self.tree.heading(df.columns.values[x], text=df.columns.values[x], command=self.populate_selection)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        self.tree.insert("",0,text=index,values=list(row))

    self.tree.grid(row=50,column=0,rowspan=1,columnspan=12,sticky=N+E+W+S)

    self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.populate_selection)
```

Hope that helps anyone else trying this